# Assign median values by separating data to bins

Tags: python, pandas, median

I have a dataframe which I want to separate into bins and assign each bin the median value of the values in that bin.

```
   POA   Egrid           
   200   1.17
   205   0.63
   275   1.08
   325   1.22
   350   0.57
```

The result should look like

```
   POA       Egrid           
 (200,300)   Median of (1.17,0.63,1.08)
 (300,400)   Median of (1.22,0.57)
```

I tried to write two loops, but couldn't figure out the median part. Any help would be good.

Comment: What is the logic of creating the bin? Once you create a column for the bin you can compute the median using `groupby`. Can you explain the logic behind bin? Is it every 100 increment, like 100-200, 200-300, 300-400, etc?

Comment: You can create 100 increment bins using this. This will create from from 0 - 1000. Then groupby and transform. `df['POA'] = pd.cut(df['first'], np.linspace(0, 10000, 101), include_lowest=True)`
`df['Egrid'] = df.groupby('POA')['Egrid'].transform('median')`

Comment: That works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do with

```
s=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.POA,[100,200,300])).Egrid.median().reset_index()
          POA  Egrid
0  (100, 200]  1.170
1  (200, 300]  0.855
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `pd.cut` and `.groupby` and `.transform`

```
import pandas as pd
df['POA'] = df['POA'].astype(int)
df['POA'] = pd.cut(df['POA'], [0,99,199, 299, 399], include_lowest=True)
df['Egrid'] = df.groupby('POA')['Egrid'].transform('median')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df
```

EDIT:

There is a flag with `pd.cut` that is `right=False`. If we add this in, then the categories are much cleaner and instead of going to 99, you can go to 100.

```
import pandas as pd
df['POA'] = df['POA'].astype(int)
df['POA'] = pd.cut(df['POA'], [0,100,200, 300,400], include_lowest=True, right=False)
df['Egrid'] = df.groupby('POA')['Egrid'].transform('median')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df
```

output:

```
    POA         Egrid
0   [200, 300)  1.080
1   [200, 300)  1.080
2   [200, 300)  1.080
3   [300, 400)  0.895
4   [300, 400)  0.895
```

Comment: Thanks @Chinmay please accept this or another answer as solution if it helped you solve.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly isn't the most efficient way to do it, but this would work!

First, let's recreate a similar setting:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# make a DataFrame like yours
df = pd.DataFrame([[200, 1.17], [205, 0.63], [275, 1.08], [325, 1.22], [350, 0.57]], columns=["POA", "Egrid"])
```

Then, let's add the medians:

```
# first, define a list of possible ranges from which you want the medians
list_of_ranges = [(200, 300), (300, 400)]

# initialize a column named "Median"
df["Median"] = [0]*df.shape[0]

# apply median to the desired ranges
for a, b in list_of_ranges:
    
    # calculate the median from the desired subset of the dataframe
    median = df[(df['POA'] >= a) & (df['POA'] < b)]["Egrid"].median()
    
    # apply the value where the condition is respected
    df.loc[(df['POA'] >= a) & (df['POA'] < b), 'Median'] = median
```

Please tell if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframe
d = {'POA':[200,205,275,325,350], 'Egrid':[1.17,0.63,1.08,1.22,0.57]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create bins to group by
bins = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]

# For loop to assign each POA to a bin
for bin in bins:
    upper_bin = bin + 100
    df.loc[(df['POA'] >= bin) & (df['POA'] < upper_bin), 'Bin'] = f'{bin} to {upper_bin}'

# Create a pandas pivot_table to summarize the results
# Displays each bin and its median value
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Bin'], values=['Egrid'], aggfunc=np.median)
print(df2)
```

Comment: Certainly, I should've included comments in my post. First I created a dataframe with the provided data. Second I created a list of various bins we'd like to group. I then used a for loop to assign each POA to a bin. Lastly, I used a pandas pivot table to summarize the results showing each bin and the median value.